# Joomla - языковые ключи ru-RU en-GB

Tags: joomla

Делаю тему для Joomla, пытаюсь добавить alt текст для логотипа alt="[?php echo  JText::_('TPL_NEW_LOGO');?]"

Тема называется NEW. Знаю что языковые ключи читаются только раз при установке темы, дальше файлы копируются в корень Joomla ( {joomla_root}\language\en-GB\en-GB.tpl_new.ini). Так вот, я добавляю новый ключ TPL_NEW_LOGO = "Company logo" , но в весртке не отображается, т.е. как будто бы я этот файл пустой.

Почему так? Должно по итогу получиться так [img src="..." alt="**Company logo**"], а получатся [img src="..." alt="**TPL_NEW_LOGO**"]

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решился следующим образом:
`Общие настройки-Система-Отладка языка - Да`,
проверить на фронтенд странице информацию о подключенных языках (под версткой будет служебная инфа). Там указаны файлы которые Joomla пытается найти (скорее всего именно тех файлов нет)